# Subscript out of range - depending on user

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook that houses several macros, 4 of them are "settings" macros that write information to certain cells, while the final "tool" macro is one that references the cells written in by the other macros when it runs.

The "Tool" macro works fine.  The problem lies within the "Settings" macros.

There are 2 different kinds of "Settings" macros, 2 of them open a file explorer so that the user may choose the "Source" and "Destination" documents and then prints the path of the file into their respective cells, while the other 2 open up the "Source" document so that the user may highlight the cells they want to copy.

This whole process had been working fine, until one of my coworkers came up to me and said that they were getting errors when they tried to run the 2 "Settings" macros that print the range and location of cells.

[All 4 "Settings" macro codes are here.](http://pastebin.com/AqCYNiRz)

The two macros that are giving problems are *ChangeDataWithLoop* and *HeaderLocationsWithLoop*.

The error appears on the same line of code on both macros.

```
    SrcPath = Workbooks("Data Tool 2").Worksheets("Data Tool Settings").Cells(6, 3).Value
```

The error is #9

> Subscript out of range.

I have so far been unable to recreate the error on my machine, but the error has been repeated by another coworker logged into a different machine.

I am completely stumped.  Please help!

Other Information:

- The name of the workbook that holds all 5 macros is "Data Tool 2" and it is located on a network drive.
- The name of the worksheet with settings on it is "Data Tool Settings"
- I am listed as the author of the document. (Not sure if important)
- The document is not protected.

Comment: This should only happen if the workbook name or worksheet name is invalid. For one thing I always use the full name (with the extension) of the workbook, e.g. `Data Tool 2.xls`. I would test these one by one with some helper functions, e.g. http://pastebin.com/MYadsMgw

Comment: I was able to fix it by changing "Workbooks("Data Tool 2").Worksheets" to simply Sheets.  Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed "Workbooks("Data Tool 2").Worksheets" to Sheets.  Works fine - tested multiple times on multiple machines/user ids.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1) Check if all users have their file extension being shown under folder option (i.e. Data Tool 2.xlsm)
2) Try remove spaces on workbook / worksheet name to avoid hidden ascii character
3) Check the dedicated cells value.  Does it contains some character that might not be readable to all? (i.e. specific for a language)

Comment: For whatever reason, changing "Workbooks("Data Tool 2").Worksheets" to "Sheets" worked.  Thank you for the help though!

Comment: @Reamithey Glad to help~  The reason changing into "Sheet"s works is that it avoids stating specifically which workbokk's sheet, and use whatever workbook your precedning code is referencing.  That could also conclude that the error comes from the workbooks("Data Tool 2")